# Bash: Split text file ahead of regex match

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I'd like to split a text file (1000-2000 lines) after 55 "displayed" lines. To count the actual numbers of lines displayed,

`grep -n "^L 7p 39 C\|^N 2" airportdata.txt | cut -f1 -d: >> matches_all.txt`

works as desired.

Now I have the total of the displayed lines including line numbers where the "displayed content" is located.

**My problem:** I'm only allowed to split the file in front of `N 2` (see sample content) to preserve the file structure. I'm not sure how to achieve this. My try was to look if match number 56 is `N 2`. Then the split is easy:

```
head -55 airportdata.txt > apd_1.txt
tail -n +55 airportdata.txt > apd_2.txt
```

does the trick while keeping the file structure intact.

If I match one of the other lines, I have to "walk up" in the file and find a line with a lower line count which has `N 2` in it and split the file there. And exactly this is the part where I didn't succeed so far.

Any ideas are highly welcome.

All the best,

Chris

---

**File structure:**
`N n` defines the numbers of columns. The following lines are distributed into these columns until there is a change with a new `N n`.

`N 2` means two columns, so the next two lines make up one "displayed line".

`N 9` means nine columns, each nine lines following make up one "displayed line".

**Sample content** of `airportdata.txt`:

```
N 2
L 7p 40 L @:6.5p:CYLW@::
L 7p 39 R 1410ft / nil
N 9
L 7p 39 L 1
L 7p 39 L 16
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 C 2500*x61
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R 34
L 7p 39 R -
N 2
L 7p 40 L @:6.5p:CYMJ@::
L 7p 39 R 1890ft / nil
N 9
L 7p 39 L 1
L 7p 39 L 11L
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 C 2500 x46
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R 29R
L 7p 39 R 1
L 7p 39 L G
L 7p 39 L 11R
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 C 2200 x46
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R 29L
L 7p 39 R G
N 2
L 7p 40 L @:6.5p:CYVR@::
L 7p 39 R 10ft / n.a
N 9
L 7p 39 L 3
L 7p 39 L 08L
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 C 3000 x61
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R 26R
L 7p 39 R 3
L 7p 39 L 3
L 7p 39 L 08R
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 C 3500*x61
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R 26L
L 7p 39 R 1
L 7p 39 L 1
L 7p 39 L 12
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 C 2200 x61
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R 30
L 7p 39 R G
N 2
L 7p 40 L @:6.5p:CYWG@::
L 7p 39 R 780ft / 8
N 9
L 7p 39 L 2
L 7p 39 L 36
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 C 3300 x61
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R 18
L 7p 39 R V
L 7p 39 L 1
L 7p 39 L 13
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 C 2600 x61
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R 31
L 7p 39 R 1
```

Adapted to the sample content a possible result would be:

Condition: split after 4 displayed lines

`apd_1.txt`:

```
N 2
L 7p 40 L @:6.5p:CYLW@::
L 7p 39 R 1410ft / nil
N 9
L 7p 39 L 1
L 7p 39 L 16
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 C 2500*x61
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R 34
L 7p 39 R -
```

`apd_2.txt`:

```
N 2
L 7p 40 L @:6.5p:CYMJ@::
L 7p 39 R 1890ft / nil
N 9
L 7p 39 L 1
L 7p 39 L 11L
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 C 2500 x46
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R 29R
L 7p 39 R 1
L 7p 39 L G
L 7p 39 L 11R
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 L \040
L 7p 39 C 2200 x46
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R \040
L 7p 39 R 29L
L 7p 39 R G
[and all the rest]
```

The fifth matched line is not `N 2` and therefore the cut has to be made in front of the previous `N 2`

Comment: Would like to help but I don't think I fully understand the problem. Just as a hint: Csplit might be helpful here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html

Comment: if you recast your problem as 5 lines, instead of 56 lines, it will be easy for people to visualize the result you're asking for. Good luck.

Comment: Are you fixed on bash?  It might be easier in perl or ruby where you ould more easily do a bit of look ahead.

Comment: I think you need to be more clear about what a "displayed line" is: it is a number of lines of text from the file that is delimited by... or contains ... ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand all your conditions, but I think simplest would be using a loop, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
apd=0
while read line; do
  [[ $line == "N 2"* ]] && apd=$(($apd+1))
  echo "$line" >> "add_${apd}.txt"
done < "airportdata.txt"
```

Which on your sample `aiportdata.txt` will output 4 files `add_1.txt add_2.txt add_3.txt add_4.txt` each starting with `N 2`

Comment: This nicely splits the file at every mention of `N 2`. The desired result would be a split ahead of the `N 2` with a line number in the `matches_all.txt` file =< 56.

Comment: @Chris So basically it should split every 56 lines or when it encounters `N 2`?

Comment: Not really – I try my best to explain it in another way: The file `airportdata.txt` is used to fill a box with a max capacity of 55 lines. Not every line in the file is printed as the lines are parsed into several columns and the file may only be split at `N 2`. This may lead to a "visible" line count of less than 55 (less than 55 lines in the box). The `grep` in the question is an approximation: It matches the middle column of a 9-column line and the beginning a new airport set. But the result is close enough to use as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, then you're looking for something like this:

```
awk -v n=55 -v f1=apd_1.txt -v f2=apd_2.txt '
    /^N/ {++c}
    c <= n { print > f1 }
    c > n { print > f2 }
' < airportdata.txt
```

That is:

- Pass some variables to `awk`: `n` = the "threshold" number to split, `f1` and `f2` the two output files
- If a line starts with `N`, increment the count
- If the count is less than or equal the threshold, print to the 1st file
- If the count is greater than the threshold, print to the 2nd file

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Unfortunately this is not the split I am looking for. Just looking for the `N n` occurrences doesn't cut it. The `n=55` is valid for all the resulting lines in `matches_all.txt`. But the cut can only be made if the next line is an `N 2`. So it becomes more of an n=<55. Sorry for my English.

Comment: @Chris it seems to me that you could achieve what you want by adjusting the `n=55` setting there (change to `n=56`? or `n=54`?), or by adjusting the `c <= n`, `c > n` conditions inside. No?

Comment: Enjoy the infinite loop getline will provide some day down the road when you least expect it :-). Read http://awk.info/?tip/getline and make sure you fully understand all the caveats before using getline.